# Power to detect significant correlation given measurement uncertainty

Tags: correlation, error, uncertainty

First of all, apologies if some of the technical terminology in here is not accurate - my experience with statistics is fairly limited.

To illustrate my problem, let's say I wanted to design a study to calculate a linear correlation between IQ and head circumference (HC) as measured with a tape. The human makes a measurement error of 0.1 cm on average, and errors are randomly distributed.

How do I determine how many subjects need to be enrolled in the study in order for me to detect a statistically significant correlation between IQ and HC? Is it possible to determine this a priori, or is this dependent on how strong the correlation turns out to be?

Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: A priori is best, but you need to answer this question: how small could the actual correlation be and still be important to you? Not asking you to guess the result, but rather what's important scientifically.

Comment: To help with intuition on the above, visualize a scatterplot of the future data, framed in a square plotting region. If the shape of the scatter is like an Idaho potato, the correlation is about .5; cucumber, .9; zucchini, .95; green bean, .99. Everything you need to know about correlation can be found at the farmer's market :)